# Conversion between numeric objects in Java

Tags: java, numbers

I am looking for a simple, concise way to convert a given Number object to an object of a given numeric type.

- Loss of precision due to narrowing conversions is fine
- I prefer not to go through strings.

I need something like:

```
private static Number convert(Number num, Class<? extends Number> targetType)
```

Is there a way to do it without checking all the combinations of types?

Comment: Regardless of the implementation, I'd at least rewrite the method signature as `public static <N extends Number> N convert(Number number, Class<N> type)`. This would return exactly the specified number type, which can have advantages in postprocessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the clearest way is to use brute force:

```
private static Number convert(Number num, Class<? extends Number> targetType) {
    Number result = null;
    if (Byte.class.equals(targetType)) {
        result = Byte.valueOf(num.byteValue());
    } else if (Short.class.equals(targetType)) {
        result = Short.valueOf(num.shortValue());
    } else if (...) {
         ...
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("targetType is not a Number");
    }
    return result;
}
```

You might use reflection, but I find that more hackish.

Comment: +1 to avoid reflection. Reflection will slow down the application... I would do it exactly the same.

Comment: Nice. I will use this solution. With the static methods of these types there is no need to actually check all type combinations. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like:

```
String simpleName = targetType.getSimpleName().toLowerCase();
if (simpleName.equals("integer")) {
   simpleName = "int";
}
Method m = number.getClass().getMethod(simpleName + "Value");
return (Number) m.invoke(number);
```

This relies on the fact that `Number` has methods like `longValue()`, `floatValue()`, etc.

As for `BigInteger` or `AtomicInteger` - you can use their constructor reflectively, which accepts one argument - the primitive type.

Comment: +1. Would need to check that the types `AtomicInteger`, `AtomicLong`, `BigDecimal`, `BigInteger`, aren't passed in as targetType as they don't have a xxxValue() method on `Number`.

Comment: @Noel M: I don't need to handle these types. However, now I realize that performance IS important. I may consider the verbose solution instead... Anyway, I like the creativity of this solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps converting via `BigDecimal` would work?

Comment: I suspect this requires either converting to String or using reflection, right?